# How do I put my comment form above the comments?

Tags: themes, comments

The default way to do things seem to have the comment form below the comments. I'd like to have the form at the top. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

The comment list is output via `wp_list_comments()`, and the comment-reply form is output via `comment_form()`; so, just ensure that you call `comment_form()` **before** you call `wp_list_comments()`.

Comment: Hi Chip. In which file are those calls invoked?

Comment: @bob Your theme has several files that control the presentation of various page types ([chart](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)). Posts are usually controlled by `single.php` unless your theme is doing something fancy with custom post types. Inside `single.php` you should find calls to both of the functions Chip mentioned. You can edit the file and experiment with placement to get what you want.

Comment: @bob comment markup is defined in `comments.php`, which is invoked in the Theme template files via `comments_template()`.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the 'comments.php' file is present in the theme I'm building, but wordpress isn't using it. It must be falling back to something, because the comment thread and form are still being displayed. Where is the file that wordpress falls back to for displaying comments?

Comment: Legacy support (i.e. WordPress using a "fallback" template-part file) has been deprecated, and should not be relied on. Instead, ensure that `single.php`, `page.php`, and any other template file from which you wish to call the comments markup includes the `<?php comments_template(); ?>` template tag, which is what includes the comments markup in the template file.

Comment: But when comments_template is being called, and comments.php isn't present (or is being ignored), which template gets used? I'm using 3.2.1, and my own comments template is simply being ignored, but I'm still seeing markup around comments. I'd like to edit whatever file is being called, so I can finally get the comments form to appear above the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed a temporary solution for one of my pages, and I didn't want to edit my theme files, so I just put this in my page using the "text" tab of the page editor. Maybe it'll help someone else in a similar situation:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var respond = document.querySelector("#respond");
  var commentsArea = respond.parentNode;
  commentsArea.removeChild(respond);
  commentsArea.insertBefore(respond, commentsArea.firstChild);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this with CSS flex-box:

```
#comments {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#respond{
  order: 2;
}
.comment-list {
  order: 3;
}
```